# How to convert http to git SSH protocol?

Tags: git, http, dokku, paas, gitea

I want to push mirror from Gitea to [Piku](https://github.com/piku/piku) (Paas like Dokku and Heroku)
but Gitea only support http push mirror and Piku only support ssh. How can translate the http request (clone, pull, push, fetch) with http:// url (http://example.com/example.git) from Gitea and send to Piku with ssh protocol (git@example.com:example)?

I have try push Gitea with http git request to Piku with ssh but fail to do so.

Comment: Gitea definitely supports SSH. Who is hosting it? Have they disabled SSH?

Comment: Are you asking about Gitea pushing to Piku, or you pushing to both Gitea and Piku from your system?

Comment: Pusing from Gitea to Piku